# What is a common naming convention for RAII classes?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, raii

In C++, when using the Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII) pattern, are there any common conventions for naming the classes?

In my case, I have classes which do the following kinds of things and I would like names which are likely to invoke a useful meaning to a first time reader when seeing one of these on the stack:

- A class to suppress logging (which can be nested).
- A class to put in place an observer.
- A class to record the current object being processed for the current thread.
- A derived class to process the object in addition to the base class behavior (in prior line).

As a first cut, I have used names like these (in corresponding order to above), but hope to improve upon them:

- class SuppressLogger
- class ScopedObserver
- class WithCurrentObject
- class WithObjectProcessed : public WithCurrentObject

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with those names.  I might prepend `Log` to the last two (e.g. `LogWithCurrentObject`), but depending on the code, that might not be necessary.

Comment: In case you are wondering how to name a RAII wrapper of a resource, you can check out for example [the wrappers defined in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) or [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RAII should be used all throughout the language. Since it should be the default, there's is no naming convention to follow.

Comment: True, but there's a difference between a class that *happens* to implement RAII, and a class whose *focus* is RAII (to the extent of not having any methods other than a constructor and destructor).  I assume William is asking about the latter.